# Copying images from iMessage creates duplicates

Tags: messages

This is extremely annoying problem. Few months ago I've forwarded few panoramas to a friend and it crashed her phone. Today I tried to copy & paste few select pictures and instead whole pack times 8 was about to get sent. Even more frustratingly, drag & drop of selected photos from iMessage copies just one item. Copy and paste is trying to copy 25x items and crashes top of the line MBP.

Screenshots below

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, your question seems unclear to me.  What are you asking?  Is it possible to send one photo at a time through iMessage, is that the question?

Comment: Is it possible to send multiple photos?

Comment: Yes it is, I do so quite often.

Comment: How? Because iMessage forwards tons of pictures.